# combine glortho with shader code

Tags: opengl, shader, gpu, fbo

### **Edit + Summary for better clarity:**

My code does this: given an image, it modifies it (using shaders). It outputs it to a texture. Then an old opengl code (using glOrtho) moves and rescales this image to where it should be displayed on screen.

**My question: How do I change my current shaders code to include this translation and rescaling?**

---

My current pipeline is this (see code below):

**image --> modern opengl processing --> render to texture T --> use old opengl to render texture T to screen**

but I want it to be like this:

**image --> modern opengl processing --> modern opengl render directly to screen given coordinates**

So basically my question is:

**given screen coordinates in glOrtho, how do I change my shaders code below to render to the given coordinates, while still performing my enhancements?**

Here's a sketch of my current code:

```
//render to texture T
RenderEnhancementIntoTexture(T);  

//bind this texture:
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, T);

//clean-up shaders, vertices, return to fixed-pipeline:
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
glUseProgram(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);


//position the canvas on screen based on the gui:
glOrtho(l, r, b, t, 0, 10.0);

//use this texture to paint on the screen segment:
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(left, bottom,  -5);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( right, bottom,  -5);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( right, top,  -5); // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(left,  top,  -5);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
glEnd();
```

And the shaders code:

the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 VertexPosition;
uniform vec2 u_step;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(VertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```
//simple example - just output the pixel value:
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform vec2 u_step;
out vec4 FragmentColor;

void main(void)
{
  vec3 accum = texture( image, vec2(gl_FragCoord)*u_step ).rgb;
  FragmentColor = vec4(accum , 1.0);
}
```

and the code to initialize the vertices:

```
void initVAO(void)
{
    GLuint positionLocation = 0;

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    { 
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 
        1.0f, -1.0f, 
        1.0f,  1.0f, 
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 
    };

    GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2 };

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjID[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)positionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjID[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Comment: Wait, what's the problem again?

Comment: I've added an explanation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this complicated piece of code:

> ```
> //position the canvas on screen based on the gui:
> glOrtho(l, r, b, t, 0, 10.0);
>
> //use this texture to paint on the screen segment:
> glBegin(GL_QUADS);
> glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(left, bottom,  -5);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
> glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( right, bottom,  -5);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
> glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( right, top,  -5); // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
> glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(left,  top,  -5);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
> glEnd();
> ```

All you want to do (as far as I understood you) is, that your textured quad covers the whole viewport. Well, nothing easier than that. Instead of an ortho projection and some modelview transformation just use identity transforms and specify the vertices directly in clip space. The boundaries of the viewport always are the the coordinates -1 and 1 of NDC space. And with an identity transform all the way through clip space == ND space.

So just use the vertex positions (-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1) and (-1,1) and pass them right through to `gl_Position` in the vertex shader.

Comment: I'm modifying an existing image. Then the glOrtho code moves and rescales this image to where it should be displayed on screen. How do I change my current code to include this translation and rescaling? The code is complicated since I've gotten into the middle of old opengl code that renders. I needed to use shaders to enhance the image (doing gpgpu); but didn't want to change the entire pipeline. This code actually works; I'm just trying to save some processing to save time. Thus - I want to render on screen directly, instead of the an FBO, and then to screen again.

Comment: @zuuz: Do you have the coordinates in window pixel coordinates? If so, just use glViewport to place it in the window. If it's relative to the viewport well, then your approach is not bad, but keep the vertices z=0 and use near=-1, far=1 for the ortho projection matrix you build using the functions provided by GLM, Eigen (GL), linmath.h or similar.